# Querying Snowflake in Python where the table may not exist

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I got this code from a coworker that gets and manipulates data from Snowflake using snowflake.connector:

```
with read_snowflake(user = snf_user, warehouse = snf_warehouse, database = snf_db, schema = snf_schema) as snf_conn:
    max_date_df = pd.read_sql(max_date_qry, snf_conn) #Read
```

However, when the table doesn't exist (and therefore I need to feed the algorithm a default date value) I couldn't figure out how to trap the error.  I did figure out how to trap that specific error with this code:

```
snf_conn = read_snowflake(user = snf_user, warehouse = snf_warehouse, database = snf_db, schema = snf_schema)
cur = snf_conn.cursor()
try:
    cur.execute(max_date_qry)
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Some error you don't know how to handle {e}")
    max_date = '2023/01/01'
```

But then when I try to read the results from the simple `SELECT MAX(SN_DATE) MAX_DT FROM db.tbl.N_SNAPSHOT` query (which returns a single date from Snowflake) the `print(cur)` output spits out numerals ranging from 1 to 52 (with 9 twice).

How can I query Snowflake for a max date and also trap the potential "table doesn't exist" error?

Comment: Put the code that calls `cur.fetchone()` and assigns to `max_date` inside the `try` block. It will be skipped if the exception happens.

Comment: @Barmar after the `cur.execute(max_date_qry)`?

Comment: Oh I see, I had to close out the run instance, looks like VS Code was retaining old values.